# Reload UIWebView when a new push notification arrives

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm fairly new to Objective-C programming but trying hard :-). I'm developing a small app that has 2 UIWebViews (accessed via 2 toolbar buttons).

I've implemented the push notification service and it all works fine...

What I would like to do now is reload the UIWebView when I receive a new push notification.
I'm guessing it should go in my AppDelegate.m in :

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *) application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *) userInfo {
```

I would like to do something like :

```
[FirstUIWebView reload];
```

but I don't know how to control the view from the appdelegate..

Your help would be greatly appreciated..

Romain

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `UIViewController*` property in the appDelegate class that references the controller containing the `UIWebView*` view object. The controller would expose the `IBOutlet UIWebView*` property referencing the view.

Then you can call reload the `UIWebView` from the appDelegate method such as:

```
[webViewController.webView reload]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply so I did
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *webViewController;
in AppDelegate.h

how do I get this webViewController to reference my controller (FirstViewController) that contains the UIWebView (reservationWebView) I'm trying to reload ?

Thanks again, sorry for the probably stupid question..
Romain

Comment: The way to initialize the controller would be: self.webViewController = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

Comment: The "WebViewController" is the .xib file name.

Comment: ok, so I would do this in "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" : self.webViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"webViewController" bundle:nil]; Only problem is I use storyboards. I did set the identifier to FirstIdentifier on my the View and tried to work it out with the solution provided here : http://tinyurl.com/6nld23c unfortunately it still won't work ...

Comment: I declared a Storyboard like so : @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIStoryboard *storyboard; and then in the m file :
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    self.webViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstIdentifier"];
and then I tried to use [webViewController.webView reload]; but I can't get to webView in the webViewController.. I feel like I'm getting closer though .!? Tkx again

Comment: and then I tried to use [webViewController.reservationWebView reload]; but I can't get to reservationWebView in the webViewController.. I feel like I'm getting closer though .!? Tkx again

Comment: Once you instantiate the controller, push it to either a navigation controller (recommended) [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; or to the view [self.view pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

The UIWebView can be instatiated through the code [[UIWebView alloc] init] or better yet linked to the owner through the XIB edito. I am not sure where the storyboard fits in and I have never used them.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your reply. I have to look into storyboarding a little deeper...